# Searching array of substrings for specific string (VBA)

Tags: arrays, string, vba, date, substring

I am writing code to process incoming e-mails.  Most aspects are working correctly; however, processing of the date is giving me some trouble.  The EvaluateDate function I defined in Module1 is not working properly.  There is no error when I run it, there is just no output.  Tabl is an array of substrings.  Incoming e-mails are split into substrings by line.  So, basically each index of the array is a line from the e-mail.  I am looking to search for a particular month and then assign "01/" for January and so forth.  Incoming emails are as such "Thursday, October 20, 2011" and would like to be processed to "10/20/11".  Everything is of the String type.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need more of the other code to determine the source of the problem.  Thanks.

In Sheet 1 code,

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim olExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim olSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim myArray(8) As String
Dim Line As Long, Addr1 As String
Dim Tabl, str As String
Dim index As Integer
Dim I As Integer, x As Integer, N As Integer, j As Integer

Sheets("EditData").Select
Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"
'Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

On Error Resume Next
 ' Getting the messages selection
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olExp = olApp.ActiveExplorer
Set olSel = olExp.Selection
 ' Checking if there is at least one message selected
If olSel.Count < 1 Then
    MsgBox "No message selected", vbExclamation, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
With Sheets("EditData")
     ' Retrieving the first avaible row to put message in
    Line = .Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
     ' looping through message
    For x = 1 To olSel.Count
        DoEvents
        Erase myArray
        mybody = Replace(olSel.Item(x).body, Chr(13), "")

        ' Splitting the message body into an array of substrings,
        ' using the "line feed" characters as separators
        mybody = Replace(mybody, Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
        Tabl = Split(mybody, Chr(10))
        For Each Item In Tabl
            Item = Replace(Item, Chr(10), "")
            Item = Application.Clean(Item)
        Next Item

        ' Looping through these substrings
        For I = 0 To UBound(Tabl)

            ' Date Received Start
            If LCase(Left(Tabl(I), 4)) = "sent" Then
                m = Module1.EvaluateDate(Tabl)
                .Cells(Line, 2) = m
            End If
       Next I
     Next X
   End With
 End Sub
```

In Module1,

```
 'Function to determine the month, day, and year in this format mm/dd/yy
    Public Function EvaluateDate(Tabl As Variant) As Variant
    For I = 0 To UBound(Tabl)
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "January", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "01/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "February", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "02/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "March", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "03/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "April", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "04/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "May", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "05/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "June", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "06/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "July", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "07/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "August", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "08/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "September", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "09/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "October", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "10/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "November", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "11/"
        End If
        If InStr(1, Tabl(I), "December", 1) > 0 Then
            m = "12/"
        End If
    Next I
    EvaluateDate = m
End Function
```

Comment: Please fix your code with appropriate formatting.

Comment: vb6, vba, vbscript, or vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1) In a VBA function, you need to assign a return value using the name of the function. Your code is missing something like this:

```
EvaluateDate = m
```

Also, the return value for EvaluateDate can be a String:

```
Public Function EvaluateDate(Tabl As Variant) As String
```

2) Your Tabl variable is declared as Variant, which is actually correct, but you think it is a String.

```
Dim Tabl, str As String
```

this actually means:

```
Dim Tabl As Variant, str As String
```

You can share a Dim statement, but not a declaration.

Also note that you haven't declared "mybody" or "m" in your button code.

3) When your code enters the appropriate If statement and finds a match on the month name, you should be exiting the loop. I would rewrite the For loop in EvaluateDate like this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(Tabl)
    Select Case True
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "January", 1) > 0
      m = "01/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "February", 1) > 0
      m = "02/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "March", 1) > 0
      m = "03/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "April", 1) > 0
      m = "04/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "May", 1) > 0
      m = "05/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "June", 1) > 0
      m = "06/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "July", 1) > 0
      m = "07/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "August", 1) > 0
      m = "08/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "September", 1) > 0
      m = "09/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "October", 1) > 0
      m = "10/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "November", 1) > 0
      m = "11/"
    Case InStr(1, Tabl(i), "December", 1) > 0
      m = "12/"
    End Select
  Next i
```

4) You have this line in your code:

```
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
```

This will cause auto-instantiation (see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx for why this is bad). Simply declare the variable, since you are already creating it later in your code.

5) In your button code you loop through each line of the email, but then you pass the whole email to the EvaluateDate function and loop through every line again. So if my math is correct you are looping n*n times through the email when you only need to loop n times. Is that really what you want?

Comment: 1) Are you saying in my when I call it from the code in my sheet to have EvaluateDate=m?  
2) Tabl is declared As String.  Does VBA let you access a String by its index as well as an array?  I have variable decs, but did not include them.  Should I be using variant?  
3) I thought the first index would be 0.  It is changed now, but hasn't solved the problem.  
4) It shouldn't.  Is there a a way to break out of the If statement after assigning m to the corresponding numbered month?  
I am inexperienced with VBA as you can see, but need to learn for my job.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an example of how you are populating the Tabl variable, including sample input and the source of the emails (Outlook?)

Comment: I have edited my question with updated code.  Good news is I am getting an output now.  Bad news is that it is incorrect.  Yes, I am using Outlook.  I cannot send you an e-mail that I am working with but I can make one up that will suffice for this purpose.  What is your e-mail?

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at this and post an answer as soon as I can, unless someone beats me to it!

Comment: WOW! Just spent too much time trying to figure out why the output kept on coming back "05/" for every month.  Maybe because at the end of every e-mail the word may is used in the sense that you MAY call this one solved!  Thanks for your help.  I'll definitely be referring to your website in the future.  Next step is moving the e-mails to another folder after they have been processed to Excel.  I already saw you had something posted on that so I'll start there.

Comment: I simply searched for "y, May" instead of just "May" to solve that issue btw.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but I haven't really answered your question. I'd rather you open it up some if someone else provides a better answer, you can mark the best answer.

Comment: I tried to improve my answer. I found a few more things, please review and let me know. FYI we shouldn't really use the comments for back and forth discussion (my fault).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response.  I understand things more clearly now.  I do believe your math is correct.  Two for loops will have a run time of n^2.  I believe it should work with only one for loop, thus reducing it to n.  I do not know how to reply to you without using this comment.  It asked me to automatically move this discussion to chat, but since I just joined my reputation needs to improve to have that privilege.